# Kendo Grid: Undo Row Selection Event

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid with AngularJS. I am having real trouble getting change event to not fire based on some condition. I am trying the following approach but doing so has no effect.

```
change: function (e){
     if(somecodition)
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

how can I stop user from changing row (based on some condition)

---

ended up implementing the following solution. thanks for the help from [dimodi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3086237/dimodi)

**Solution**

```
var lastRow;
function onSelection(e){
  var row = e.sender.element.find(".k-state-selected");      
  if(/*some condition*/) {
    row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
    e.sender.select(lastRow);
  }
  else {
    lastRow= row;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `change` event cannot be prevented, however, you can save the current selection in each event firing, and if needed, restore the previous selection with the Grid's `select` method. Beware not to enter an endless loop when using the `select` methid in a `change` handler.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select